# How to change Number format in oracle?

Tags: oracle, globalization

I have a requirement to globalize the application based on culture specified in config file.

I have Amounts and date values .I decided to convert them in query itself.Like below

For Spanish Chile `Es-CL`:

for Date format is "dd-mm-yyyy"   I will use `Select TO_CHAR(busdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') from itemTable.`

Similarly i want to use same for the amounts `Select to_char(Amount,'99.999.99,00')  from table1.`

But its in vain.

Please suggest me the right way to achive my requirement.

These amounts and date formats can be available.but need to know how to convert them.

I thought to use in On_Data_bound event for datagrids ,but still this will be a performance issue.

Comment: Have you tried to change the nls_lang ?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams152.htm#i1130146) session variable, along with globalized [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34570):

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,';

Session altered

SQL> select to_char(123456789.01, 'fm999G999G990D00') from dual;

TO_CHAR(123456789.01,
---------------------
123,456,789.01

SQL> alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=', ';

Session altered

SQL> select to_char(123456789.01, 'fm999G999G990D00') from dual;

TO_CHAR(123456789.01,
---------------------
123 456 789,01
```