# ORA-01722: invalid number for Number datatype in oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, numbers

I am trying to insert a value in `KPI_DEFINITION` table and i am getting amn error `ORA-01722: invalid number`. The error is for `KPI_FREQUENCY` field which `NUMBER` datatype and it has trying to insert value '0,5'. I think number datatype allows integer as well as float values. But still its giving an error.

```
Insert into RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_DEF_ID,KPI_NAME,KPI_DESC,KPI_FREQUENCY) values ('10003881','Backlog Resul11t','Backlog Result11','0,5');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL numbers are **not** specified using single quotes.

Additionally: fractional digits are separated using a dot `.` not a comma. So you need to write this as:

```
Insert into RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION 
  (KPI_DEF_ID,KPI_NAME,KPI_DESC,KPI_FREQUENCY) 
values 
  ('10003881','Backlog Resul11t','Backlog Result11', 0.5);
                                                      ^
                                                      Here
```

If `KPI_DEF_ID` is also a number column, remove the single quotes for that value as well:

For a complete documentation on how to specify numbers or string literals, please see the manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#i139891

Comment: Actually i has generate this script from sql developer. And it generate in this way with '0,5'. But as we have FLOAT,DECIMAL datatype in oracle thne why it has allower decimal value in number datatype

Comment: @Rahul: `decimal` is an alias for `number(x,y)`. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#CHDHDHGB

Comment: @Rahul - you need to look at how you are generating the script then. Perhaps you are getting an existing value and using `to_char()`, with NLS settings that give you a comma for a decimal separator; and then enclosing that in quotes? If so you need to lose the quotes, and force it to use `.` as the decimal separator - so it's generated as shown in this answer.

Comment: Hello Alex you are right it was my NLS setting which is set to ',' from decimal. But i wondered why oracle has number data type which allows decimal as well. In sql developer you can see datatype with FLOAT and Decimal also. Then whats the difference between this Number,Decimal and Float data type ?

Comment: @Rahul - did you look at the docs? They explain the differences.

Comment: Yes i understood now the differences from documentation: Just a small question Alex , i am trying to change the NLS setting to make it '.' for decimal. But it didn't work. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @Rahul - that's a new question; but would probably be a duplicate of one [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15783462/266304). You can override with `to_char()` too. If you can't make it work ask a new question about that showing what you are trying.

Answer (score 2):

Possible data type for KPI_FREQUENCY in your case is `number(2,1)`
Modification of your `insert` statement

```
Insert into  RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_DEF_ID,KPI_NAME,KPI_DESC,KPI_FREQUENCY) 
    values ('10003881','Backlog Resul11t','Backlog Result11',0.5);
```

Comment: No need to change the insert query

Comment: @MaulikShah: of course the insert must be changed. `'0,5'` is not a valid number literal.